# why does eclipse show an error message when using the javadoc tag @param when commenting?

Tags: java, eclipse, settings, javadoc, java-18

I was typing some code in eclipse and as soon as I start to use the javadoc @param tag the IDE show me an error mark as seen in the picture. When I use the given solution from eclipse, the IDE corrects for example @param board to @paramboard but this is not the correct notation as I know. The javadoc tag @see don't show such error as seen in the picture. Do I miss some setting here or do I mistaken here something?

Thanks in advance!
[Screenshot of my IDE with the error mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeAOe.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening your Javadoc comment block with `/**` instead of `/*`:

**Example:**

> https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html
>
> ```
> /**
> * Returns an Image object that can then be painted on the screen. 
> * The url argument must specify an absolute <a href="#{@link}">{@link URL}</a>. The name
> * argument is a specifier that is relative to the url argument. 
> * <p>
> * This method always returns immediately, whether or not the 
> * image exists. When this applet attempts to draw the image on
> * the screen, the data will be loaded. The graphics primitives 
> * that draw the image will incrementally paint on the screen. 
> *
> * @param  url  an absolute URL giving the base location of the image
> * @param  name the location of the image, relative to the url argument
> * @return      the image at the specified URL
> * @see         Image
> */
> public Image getImage(URL url, String name) {
>   try {
>     return getImage(new URL(url, name));
>   } 
>   catch (MalformedURLException e) {
>     return null;
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: I tried your solution and now the javadoc tags get highlighted. The Error still appeared and I disabled spell checking, now it won't get error marked. It seems to be a problem with the spell checking. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Cool - glad you got it working.  The main point is that you need  the `/** ... */` comment delimiters so that the Javadoc tool can distinguish between a "Javadoc comment block" (which *SHOULD* be incorporated into the Javadoc output) and "ordinary" comments (which shouldn't).

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. That no one has told me before xD thanks again for your help.